Python - Tkinter App, Issues when calling scripts with subprocess
I have the following function which is used inside a Tkinter GUI app, for starting different other scripts (each with their own GUI's and functions) as subprocesses.
def run_external_script(script_center_root, script_name, *args):

    script_center_root.withdraw()
    script_center_root.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW", lambda: None)  # Disable close button

    base_path = getattr(sys, '_MEIPASS', os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))
    script_path = os.path.join(base_path, script_name)

    try:
        print("process started")
        process = subprocess.Popen([python_executable, script_path, *args], shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT, stdin=subprocess.PIPE )
        #process.wait()
        print("process stopped")

    except subprocess.CalledProcessError as e:
        print(f"Error: Subprocess for '{script_name}' failed with exit code {e.returncode}")
        print(f"Standard Output:\n{e.stdout}")
        print(f"Error Output:\n{e.stderr}")
        messagebox.showerror("Error", f"Could not run script: {script_name}\n{e.stderr}")
    finally:
        script_center_root.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW", lambda: close_window(script_center_root))  # Re-enable close button
        reopen_main_window(script_center_root)

When I run it directly from PyCharm it works perfectly.
When I create an exe using PyInstaller it doesn't open the scripts.
This is the .spec file
a = Analysis(
    ['main.py'],
    pathex=['.'],
    binaries=[],
    datas=[
        ('XML_to_xlsx.py', '.'),
        ('xlsx_to_PIES.py', '.'),
        ('xlsx_to_ACES.py', '.'),
        ('aces_xlsx_expand.py', '.'),
        ('aces_xlsx_rollup.py', '.'),
        ('transpose_xlsx.py', '.')
    ],
    hiddenimports=['openpyxl','pandas', 'lxml'],
    hookspath=[],
    hooksconfig={},
    runtime_hooks=[],
    excludes=[],
    noarchive=False,
    optimize=0,
)
pyz = PYZ(a.pure)

exe = EXE(
    pyz,
    a.scripts,
    a.binaries,
    a.zipfiles,
    a.datas,
    [],
    name='main',
    debug=False,
    bootloader_ignore_signals=False,
    strip=False,
    upx=True,
    console=True,
    disable_windowed_traceback=False,
    argv_emulation=False,
    target_arch=None,
    codesign_identity=None,
    entitlements_file=None,
)
coll = COLLECT(
    exe,
    a.scripts,
    a.binaries,
    a.datas,
    strip=False,
    upx=True,
    upx_exclude=[],
    name='main',
)

I need some pointers or help getting it working. I tried debugging it, but the console is showing no errors

Current working directory may not be the temporary folder created during executing the generated executable.

@acw1668 There are no issues with the file pathing. I verified the temporary folder and at execution time, all the files are there.

What is python_executable?

There will be nothing shown in the console from the being executed script because you have set stdout=subprocess.PIPE and stderr=subprocess.STDOUT when calling subprocess.Popen().
